# On comparing cardinalities of sets by finding a map

Tags: elementary-set-theory

As defined in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality), the cardinalities of sets can be compared by finding a mapping between the sets.

In particular, for nonempty sets $A$ and $B$, $|A| \le |B|$ if and only if there is an injection from $A$ to $B$.

Given only the definition, is it equivalent to saying that $|A| \le |B|$ if and only if there is a surjection from $B$ to $A$?

I guess it is true because every injection has a left-inverse which is a surjection, and every surjection has a right-inverse that is an injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement is known as the *Partition Principle* and a consequence of the Axiom of Choice.

Interestingly, it is still unknown if the Partition Principle is actually equivalent to the Axiom of Choice (many set theorists don't think so, though).